# Can I have gradle support in IDEA without importing it?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have quite big IDEA project which we incrementally migrate to gradle. I don't want to "import" newly migrated parts right now, but I do want to have IDEA support (syntax highlighting, code completion, etc) for writing gradle scripts. From brief searching it is still not obvious how to get it. Is it possible it all?

Answer (score 2):

As long you have the Groovy plugin installed and enabled, and have `*.gradle` listed as a Registered Pattern for "Groovy" in *Settings > Editor > File Types* you should get groovy features when editing a `build.gradle` file.